# How do you organize system configuration files for cfengine3?

Tags: configuration-management, cfengine

Where do you like to put system configuration files (not the cfengine language) for cfengine to copy into place?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question, but I'm not sure, so I hope this is appropriate!

In your `/var/cfengine/inputs` directory, you will have at least `promises.cf`, which is the main input file for `cf-agent`. That file can call other files in Cfengine language. This directory is likely copied from a central server somehow.

As to other files you may want to distribute, to use to copy configuration files (I'm assuming things like smb.conf for Samba, etc), I just put them in the same directory, or in a sub-directory, so they get copied everywhere and you can use them however you like.